# MySQL: Show rows with certain content last

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of product data in my DB. Each product has a certain ShopID which tells me to which shop it belongs.
**I want all products with ShopID 1,4,7 appear last in the results.**
How can I do that?

Sample Code

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE Name LIKE %red% ORDER BY ShopID ASC
```

Best Regards,
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative option would be to use a `CASE` statement in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tablename 
WHERE Name LIKE '%red%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ShopID IN (1,4,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, ShopID
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4147eb/1)

Answer (score 1):

if `ShopID` is not saved as comma separated value, you can use MySQL's `FIELD()`

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ShopID, 1,4,7) ASC, ShopID ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fb5d/1)

the reason why `1,4,7` appears on the last part of the result list is because `FIELD()` returns the index that was specified on the list. in this case, any number that is not in `1,4,7` has an index `0` making it first on the list.

- [MySQL Documentation: **FIELD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ORDER BY (ShopID IN (1, 4, 7)), ShopID
```

The `ShopID IN` expression will return 0 for rows that don't match, 1 for the rows that do.